# problem with using scanf_s to get a string value

Tags: c++, c

I try to use scanf_s to get the input from the user for the date and the month (the compiler with visual studio always asks you to use scanf_s and that is why i use it). It allows me to put in an input for the date but when I put an input for the month (as a string), it exits the code and does not execute the rest. If I placed the scanf_s for the string first, it would exit the code after I put the input in. **How would I fix this problem?**

```
#include "iostream."
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void main()
{
    char month[10];
    int date;

    printf("enter date\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &date);

    printf("enter month\n");
    scanf_s("%s", month);

    printf("Month: %s Date %d\n", month, date);
}
```

Comment: First thing to do would be call `scanf_s` properly (with the string length)...

Comment: `#include "iostream."` can't be correct. You can remove the line.

Comment: (1) `main` is, generally, expected to return `int`. Most systems block clean compilation when `main` returns other than `int` (`void` in your case). (2) It's better to make a concrete decision about the coding language you'll use prior to coding. Though it will compile most of the time, it's a good habit not to mix "C" code with "c++" code.

Comment: If this is actually C++ use `std::string` and input streams. This is pure C code in its current form.

Comment: Don't use `scanf_s`. It's just M$ trash. Disable the warning or ignore it if you can.

Comment: @John3136 I managed to get it working using this tip so thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

I just disabled the warning of scanf_s which allowed me to use scanf instead. I also tried to use the sizeof statement (e.g. scanf_s("%s", string1, sizeof string1)) this seemed to work without needing me to disable the warning.

Thank you to everyone for their help and be on the lookout for further problems I have as there are a lot more where that came from!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the size you allocated for your string, e.g.

```
scanf_s("%s", month, sizeof month);
```

Note that the call will not copy any data if the user enters more data than will fit in your buffer, including a trailing '\0'

Comment: Depending on `scanf_s()` implementation, it can be tricky to get the right type for the size.  Are you certain the return type of `sizeof` is OK?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, It may be too long, but that should not be a problem since it's the last argument.  Microsoft suggests casting it to `unsigned` on 64-bit systems, so they are only using 32 bits.

Comment: Hmmm, MS seems to want [unsigned, not size_t](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=vs-2019).  C spec wants `rsize_t/size_t`.  Good luck.