# Exception thrown in strings input output

Tags: c, string, printf

I had been having an issue with string in school project and couldn't manage to fix it, made a test program to troubleshoot but haven't had any luck. I'm trying to just make a simple program to take a string value and then print it to the console. When it tries to print the string the program crashes with an exception being thrown I don't understand I think it is trying to save the string data to a memory address it doesn't have access to but im not sure cuz I tried it on both my laptop and pc with the same issue.

"Exception thrown at 0x00007FFAACA60369 (ucrtbased.dll) in tokenizing.c.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000001F1F100000."

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string[100];
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf_s(" %s ", &string);
    printf(" %s ", string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf_s(" %s ", &string);` => ` scanf_s(" %s ", string);`

Comment: @pm100 This didn't work for me, I added a few new lines in a print function after the scan because i couldn't tell if it was crashing taking input or printing the string. it manages to print the new lines so i think the issue lies in printing the string.

Comment: The return value of `scanf` contains the number of format specifiers that were successfully read. If you read a string from the format `" %s "` the return value will be 1. Question for you: Why does that string contain spaces? Are you expecting the user to input a space character both before and after their string? Note that regardless of specifics, this approach is unsafe, and you should use `fgets` to read strings in C.

Comment: `scanf_s` in C requires the buffer size also be passed. In C++ MS provides a template overload that infers it for native character array arguments. Obviously no such think exists in C. You have to do it. When in doubt, [read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?view=msvc-140) of the functions you're calling.

Comment: One of the *many* duplicates related to this is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58924956/problem-with-using-scanf-s-to-get-a-string-value).

Comment: @pm100 `scanf_s(" %s ", string);` is broken code too.

Comment: Why are you using `scanf_s` instead of `scanf`? Is it because you are using the Microsoft compiler and it refused to let you use the function `scanf`? In that case, all you have to do is put the line `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` at the very top of your source file (before all the `#include` directives) and it will let you use that function.

Answer (score 3):

`scanf_s(" %s ", &string);` fails as it is missing a parameter.  `%s` obliges a pointer and size.

```
scanf_s(" %s ", string, (rsize_t) 100);
```

Review your compiler details on `scanf_s()` as the C standard is not followed in details by some compilers.

---

Alternative: Review `fgets()` to read a *line* into a *string*.

---

A space before `"%s"` serves no purpose.  Best to drop it.

A space after `"%s"` blocks until following non-white-space detected.  Best to drop this space too.